# BOOL method to detect if nodes have been removed from scene

Tags: boolean, sprite-kit, sknode

Im making a brick breaker type game and need to know if all the bricks have been broken in order to transition to the win screen.

The way I've been thinking of solving this is to create a BOOL method that is ran each time a brick is removed to calculate how many bricks are left. If there are no bricks left... move to the win scene.

Im struggling with the logic on how to do this.

So far I have:

```
-(BOOL)isGameWon{

for (SKNode* node in self.children){

    if ([node.name isEqual:brickCategoryName]){
        //some logic
    }

}
return YES;
}
```

didBeginContactMethod:

```
if (notTheBall.categoryBitMask == brickCategory) {
    [self runAction:_smashSound];
    [notTheBall.node removeFromParent];
    if ([self isGameWon]) {
        NSLog(@"YOU WIN!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Which part are you having a problem with? I think your logic is okay, just return NO where is says // some logic.

Comment: A thing you could use could be `[[self children] count]` (and maybe remove a few nodes that "have" to be there from the count, like the ball, etc).

Comment: Wow I had a complete blank with that. Return NO did the trick. Thanks

Comment: You can also create an SKNode named bricksNode, add only the bricks to bricksNode, add bricksNode to the scene. To check if any bricks are left, test if bricksNode.children is nil.